# firebase unauth with google doesn't allow change of user

Tags: authentication, firebase, google-oauth

Is there a setting, either in Google projects or in Firebase databases for specifying that unauth should not cache user credentials?  One I have logged into my app via the Firebase Google authentication, calling unauth() does not permit me to log in again with a different account.  An attempt to login after that immediately logs in with the old credentials without asking for a new username and password.  Closing and reopening the browser after the logout didn't help.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as you, what if the user wants to switch to another account? Seems like a bit much to ask the regular user to understand that it needs to change account permissions for my app. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase doesn't have access to your credentials when you use its Google authentication. Instead it uses OAuth to create a relationship between the Google account and your application.

When you call `unauth` Firebase expires the token that is part of the current session. But it does not remove the relationship between the Google account and your application. That's why you "automatically" get a new token when you call `auth...` next time.

It is up to each individual user to revoke the rights, which in the case of a Google account they can do at the Account Permissions page: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

Comment: I've marked this as a community wiki, because I am not at all sure whether my understanding is correct. If it is basically correct but could be expanded/clarified, please edit this answer. If my understanding is wrong, I'll delete it once somebody explains how it really works. :-)

Comment: I have this same issue. When I login with Facebook and the unath e.g. log out of my app. I then login with twitter or google and it doesnt work. But if I refresh the browser and login with twitter, then it works. Did you manage to solve this issue?